# How unintelligent can a gelatin mimic be?

Tags: fauna, intelligence, shapeshifters

The mimic resembles a transparent slime of gelatinous mass capable of changing colours and also shape.

In front of a predator, as a defense mechanism the slime mimic will shapeshift into a wobbly and bigger version of the predator.

Other species of mimics instead shapeshift into the child or opposite gender version of the predator for protection, you could easily imagine a slime lioness protecting a male lion slime and feeding him.

I want the plants to be as unintelligent as can be while also being capable of movement, mimicry and understanding the gender of other animals maybe through vision or smells or heat, not sure yet about their senses.

Can a mimic with those skills be lesser than an insect when it comes to intelligence?

Comment: looking like young is not a good idea, male lions for instance kill unfamiliar lion cubs on sight.

Comment: @John: A lot of that is smell. If the mimic smells juuust right it’s got a chance. Certainly more of a chance than if it mimics another male!

Comment: @JoeBloggs another male is better, lion males only rarely kill each other, but they basically always kill cubs they don't recognize.  As for smell just right is probably harder to achieve than looking exactly like a lion. Smell  in mammals is controlled by highly variable genes that change with each generation.

Comment: @John is it reasonable for the slime organism to release substances that inhibit the predator's ability to distinguish smell?

Comment: @Rad140 that will just get it killed faster, an get the lions ot kill their own cubs as well.

Comment: @John Lions rarely kill other lions that act like lions. If a mimic doesn’t respond appropriately to the ‘go away and stop looking at my girl’ cues then it’s probably going to get murdered, especially since it’s actually made of jello and can’t go toe to toe with the genuine article. It’s an interesting question though. Which is harder to mimic: precise pheromones or complex social behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

As unintelligent as you like, given enough time and exposure.

Great thing about evolution: it doesn’t require things to be smart to work. It requires them to work to work.

So if your shapeshifter can do nothing but recognise the male/female morphs of the top predators and shift into the appropriate forms to maximise survival: that’s enough. It doesn’t have to be a conscious decision, or even based on factors humans would recognise. A ‘plant’ that responds to male lion pheromones by transforming into a female lion shape because *that’s the best way to survive* will have more children than one that doesn’t. That lets evolution work, and that leads to utterly dumb shapeshifters that can mimic the species they evolved to mimic.

Some mimicry in nature is truly terrifying, with plants, spiders, ants, caterpillars, various cephalopods, snakes and beetles all looking, smelling and acting like other things. None of them are doing it because it’s ‘smart’. They’re doing it because it works, and that’s how they evolved. Your mimics have just evolved to do it with more than one species.

Now: there is a question of ‘what counts as intelligent’. Predators (especially successful ones) have a measure of intelligence that your mimics won’t match. Not only that, but there are significant behavioural, audible and pheromonal cues that might tip off a ‘smart’ predator that they’re dealing with a mimic. And if the mimic has evolved it’s mimicry to the point that it can successfully mimic all the behavioural cues it needs (potentially for multiple ages/morphs of multiple species) then you can argue it must be very smart itself, after all, it instinctively knows how to act like a lion/lioness/lion cub/male cheetah/female cheetah/elephant/etc/etc/etc. That requires a remarkable amount of information rammed into your mimics genetic code. It’s can still be dumb (ie can’t respond to new stimuli at all), but if it walks like a smart predator, hunts like a smart predator and smells like a smart predator then you can argue it’s as smart as a smart predator.

So really the answer very much depends on how much you want it to act like it’s targets and how handwavy you’re willing to get with evolutionary timescales. If your mimic has been evolving alongside a species for an unthinkably long time it could mimic the important bits precisely without actually being smart at all. If your mimic has only recently been introduced to a species but you need it to mimic complex behaviours and respond appropriately to social cues then it will have to be a smart cookie.

This is why it makes most sense for your mimics to be changelings, or cuckoos. They don’t mimic the ‘smart’ adult versions. They instead mimic the dumb infant stages that depend on their parents. This limits how much ‘smart’ behaviour they have to fake. With well evolved audio/pheromonal mimicry the mimic might be able to get away with it. When the ‘kids’ are growing up, the changeling plays dead, then returns to its natural state once the adults have moved on.

It’s not doing any of this consciously. It’s a potato that can cry. But it might just be enough to fool the sleep deprived new-mother-of-four cheetah into thinking she actually had five.

Comment: note cuckoo are basically unheard of in mammals, birds have fairly simple ways of recognizing young usually vison based, mammals tend towards more complex methods using many senses, possibly because there vision is poor. but good point about it being simple if you limit ot only the animals it has evolved alongside.

Comment: @john I agree cuckoos are rare in mammals, but then again so are mimics of any kind, let alone shapeshifters!

Answer (score 1):

Utterly unthinking. Quite intelligent seeming behavior can be mechanical as far as thought goes.

There's a wasp that digs a hole to serve as a nest, paralyzes a caterpillar to lay its eggs in, drags the caterpillar near the hole, and goes to check the hole, making sure nothing got it.  If the caterpillar wriggles even a bit away, the wasp will drag it back to where it left it and check the hole again.  Scientists have gotten a wasp to repeat this by shifting the caterpillar, and wasps still do it when the hole has already been checked more than forty times.

If you want it to be clear that it's not thinking, have it simply mirror the predator even in details that are unhelpful.  For instance, if a lion is hauling a dead deer, have it mirror the deer as well as the lion.

Answer (score 1):

One species will have to be a lot more intelligent than the other.

simply duplicating what is in front you is fairly simple, it would not need ot be even as smart as a rat, but recognizing sex and infancy  in  many other species is a very difficult task, especially because many species have young that look different from adults. Your are looking at at least crow like intelligence there. It is also not a good strategy many many animals will attack and eat the young of their species as long as they are not their own young. Male predators especially often kill unfamiliar young on sight, thus freeing up the female for breeding. Lions are particularly well known for this.

you could even have simpler ones that just get very big, some animals already use this approach few  predators are willing to attack things that suddenly double in size provided they don't encounter them often.